# How to make installation of linux programs easier?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, user-experience

Debian and Ubuntu provide `.deb` package files that can be installed directly. what about Fedora?

Can all tar-balls be one day `.deb` files for ease of installation ... many people lose themselves installing after gunzipping. There is a lot of code which commoners don't get an idea of when doing `./make` etc.

Comment: Only Debian and Ubuntu and their derivatives use `.deb` files. Other major Linux distributions mostly use RPM packages that have a very similar functionality.

Answer (score -1):

The biggest issue with Linux is that there isn't one.

We are talking about multiple distros which are built differently, using different libraries, applications versions and compilation flags. Even when talking about the same distro, e.g. Ubuntu 16.10 and Ubuntu 18.10, the application compiled for the latter, will not necessarily work in the former.

To solve this issue Flatpak, Snap and AppImage were created which basically package the app and all its dependencies as a package. That leads to other serious issues but at least allows ISV to package their apps which work in all Linux distros.